# Change headers in UITableView static cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have this UITableView with static cells:

[image]

I'd like to change the header field and center horizontally in the cell. How can I do using Swift?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

first of all, of course you can do this using swift, and now this is the code that you need to put in your viewController to make this work

you need to put your viewController as `UITableViewDelegate` and then implement this methods

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return X; //X is the value of height of your header
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tableView.frame.size.width, height: X)) //X is the value of height of your header
    let label = UILabel(frame: headerView.frame)
    label.text = "TESTING"
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    headerView.addSubview(label)

    return headerView;
}
```

I hope this help you

Comment: You could return the label directly as header view. no need to wrap it in an extra view.

Comment: Yes you are rigth, any subclass of UIView, but if you want to do something else in this viewHeader?, I don't know

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are wanting to use:

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

}
```

Using this you could code the UI you are looking for, create the label and set the frame to what you need and set the text to what you would want it to be.  Inside would either if check or use a switch statement for section, and set the text accordingly, then simply return the label or view, however you decide to implement your solution.  I have done something like this in a tableView footer, I'll post the code and link to the documentation for reference:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footerView = UIView.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 50))
    //label
    let label : UILabel = UILabel.init(frame: CGRectMake(30, 0, 150, 50))
    label.text = "Calorie Total :"
    //label to hold calorie total for the section
    let totalLabel = UILabel.init(frame: CGRectMake(185, 0, 50, 50))
    var total = Int()

    //grab the total for the section
    switch section {
    case 0:
        total = calculateCalories(breakfastFoodArray)
        break
    case 1:
        total = calculateCalories(lunchFoodArray)
        break
    case 2:
        total = calculateCalories(dinnerFoodArray)
        break
    case 3:
        total = calculateCalories(snackFoodArray)
        break
    default:
        break
    }
    totalLabel.text = String(total)

    footerView.addSubview(label)
    footerView.addSubview(totalLabel)

    let footerExentsionView = UIView.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 50, tableView.frame.size.width, 10))
    footerExentsionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    footerView.addSubview(footerExentsionView)
    return footerView
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: